# Result not found on shodan

Tags: networking, openssl, network-programming

recently i have been working on [shodan](https://www.shodan.io/) to gather information for my recon report. when i search my target domain it just says **Note: No results found** how is that possible? the website is up and running, but its behind CloudFlare. but i still wonder why does it not give me any results at all? what might be the reason?

It shows no results on [censys](https://search.censys.io/) either it just says **Your query returned no results.** why is it not showing me any results? does it mean the domain is virtual? but even if it is virtual how does it not show any information at all?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This means the target domain could be blocking Shodan and Censys. I would try looking for an SSL cert in the Censys Certificates Dataset with the target name on it.